# Lag in highlighting or scrolling on Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I occasionally experience lag when highlighting or scrolling on Chrome (latest, windows 7). It sometimes goes away when I switch tabs or monitors. Has anyone experienced this an know of a fix?

Answer (score 1):

Is the problem only specific to chrome or any other browser ie. Internet Explorer, Firefox, Opera etc. How many tabs do you have open? Chrome consumes a hell of a lot of memory when you have a good number of tabs open ~10 for me. It could be a caching/paging issue if you're low on RAM in the OS, this is usually my source of pain from chrome performance issues.

Comment: It can happen with only 1 tab open. I have plenty of ram.

Comment: Have you tried turning off predictive network actions in the options menu? This adds an extra layer of load to the browser, even on a seemingly idle page.
Eg. https://plus.google.com/+VincentPalmer/posts/Qdd9ePRu4WN

Comment: I've just confirmed this happens on IE as well. Sorry, guess it's not a Chrome specific problem for me.

Comment: What's your CPU usage like in the task manager? Along with this, is your antivirus doing any scan operations at the time?

Comment: CPU usage is low, no spikes. Antivirus is always running, but not doing any scanning or consuming excessive resources. I tried turning off the predictive network actions. Haven't noticed a difference.

Comment: I tried turning off the predictive network actions. Haven't noticed a difference. Thought that may be the case, especially if it's a browser wide issue. What's your ram usage situation?\